# Mongoose-Validators not validating isURL with express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose

I'm not getting an error, even though the schema should fail when I don't enter a valid url.

I can confirm that the data from the front-end is being sent correctly. It is being passed to Mongoose through the route (shown below).

There is no Err on the callback from the Hosts.Create(req.body, func...) function.

This is the schema. The validator: [validators.isURL()] is not producing a message.

```
var HostSchema = new Schema({
domain:  {
    type: String,
    required: [ true, 'A Domain is required' ],
 // This is the broken validator
    validator: [ validators.isURL({message: 'Must be a Valid URL', protocols: ['http','https','ftp'], require_tld: true, require_protocol: true} ) ]
},
pkg: {
    type: String,
    required: [ true, 'Hosting Package is required' ]
},
ssl: { type: Boolean, required: true },
maint: { type: Boolean, required: true },
...
```

});

My Route File:

```
// Process Add Cx
hosting.post('/add', function(req, res, next) {

// If No Request data.
if (req.body.constructor === Object && Object.keys(req.body).length === 0) {
    ... Send View if no form data ...

} else { // Proccess Data

    // Create new User
    Hosts.create(req.body, function(err, host) {
        if (err) return res.json({success: false, message: Hosts.MongoErrors(err)});
        // If everything was sucessful! Yay!
        res.json({success: true, message: 'Host Successfully Saved!'});
    }); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is like this:

```
validate: { 
  validator: value => validator.isURL(value, { protocols: ['http','https','ftp'], require_tld: true, require_protocol: true }),
  message: 'Must be a Valid URL' 
}
```

Comment: hahaha, thank you! I'm sure this will help someone else. The documentation isn't all too clear.

Comment: where is 'value' coming from?

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution.

```
domain:  {
    type: String,
    required: [ true, 'A Domain is required' ],
    validate: validators.isURL({message: 'Must be a Valid URL', protocols: ['http','https','ftp'], require_tld: true, require_protocol: true })
},
```